# Trying to set keyboard layout to us intl on wayland

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, wayland

I have been trying to set the keyboard layout model US and option  intl on manjaro sway (wayland)

The following commands dit not work

`localectl set-x11-keymap us intl`
`setxkbmap -layout us -variant intl`

I think that in both case it is intended for X11 and cannot find the equivalent for wayland

Comment: What's your distro? What's the content of [`/etc/vconsole.conf`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/13029#issuecomment-511010685)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and after not getting any working answer from google I just started looking for some root config file, and finally by entering here:

```bash
/etc/xdg/waybar/config
```

### Solution

I found that this file set the keyboard layout once you start the system:

```bash
/etc/sway/inputs/default-keyboard
```

So I just edited it as root and changed it to the keyboard layout I needed, in my case Latin American

```bash
sudo nano etc/sway/inputs/default-keyboard
```

### May need

You might first checkout on the list-x11-keymap-layouts, this will give you the accepted keyboard layouts to change depending on your needs, to do this just run:

```bash
localectl list-x11-keymap-layouts
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a section on the say wiki dedicated to this [here](https://github.com/swaywm/sway/wiki#keyboard-layout).

From their website:

## Input configuration

A list of input devices is available by running `swaymsg -t get_inputs`. Use the identifier for the device you want to configure in your config file:

```
input <identifier> {
    # ...config options...
}
```

Nothing prevents having multiple configurations for different specific devices:

## Default layout

```
input "1:1:AT_Translated_Set_2_keyboard" {
   xkb_layout us
}

# custom layout for an external keyboard
input "1452:591:Custom_Keyboard" {
   xkb_layout YourCustomLayout
}
```

See `man 5 sway-input` for a summary of the available options.
Keyboard layout

```
input "type:keyboard" {           # or input <identifier>
    xkb_layout us,de
    xkb_variant ,nodeadkeys
    xkb_options grp:alt_shift_toggle
}
```

See `man 7 xkeyboard-config` for options you can use with the `xkb_layout`, `xkb_model`, `xkb_options`, `xkb_rules`, and `xkb_variant` commands. Separate multiple options with commas.

User-specific settings such as symbols will be loaded from their respective directories in `~/.xkb/` or `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/xkb/`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I ll look into that asap